# RecyclerView ItemAnimator cannot animate width change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to change the size of the itemView of RecyclerView in the 'animateMoveImpl()' method for my ItemAnimator, but it did not work.

I have tried the scale animation, it works fine, but not enough.

What I want to achieve is to change the 'width' property, so the image shown in the itemView will adapt to the change. The scale animation just make the image stretched.

Is it possible to animate the width change of itemView in ItemAnimator?

Thanks~

Update:

The code is like follows.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0.5f); 
anim.setDuration(1000); 
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float tmp = DEFAULT_WIDTH * (float)animation.getAnimatedValue();
        animButton.setWidth((int)tmp);
        animButton.requestLayout();
    } 
}); 
anim.start();
```

Note that it works for normal view. But it does not work int the 'animateMoveImpl()' for ItemAnimator.

Comment: post your code what you have tried ??

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The code has been posted.